# Align abstract to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, abstract

I have the following two issues. For a university paper, I'd like to realign the abstract to fit with the rest of the page as well as putting the abstract title ("Abstract") on the same level as the text.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather than a picture of the code, you can paste the code itself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not quite sure if tha layout stays the same

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to redefine the `abstract` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {\par\noindent\textbf{\abstractname.}\ \ignorespaces}
 {\par\medskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{abstract}
Some text for the abstract, let's make sure it
goes on two or more lines.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Another}

\lipsum

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing

```
\begin{abstract}
Errors in gene expression are quite common \dots
\end{abstract}
```

type

```
\subsection*{Abstract} 
Errors in gene expression are quite common \dots
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that wokred very well. As a follow up question: What is my abstraction of subsection of? Why not \section?

Comment: @Jason - Actually, this was just an (ill-?)informed guess on my part. The command `\section` uses the relative font size `\Large`, whereas `\subsection` uses `\large`, which is 20% smaller than `\Large` but also 20% larger than `\normalsize`. (The centered "Abstract" header produced by the `abstract` *environment* uses `\normalsize`.) If you want the `\Large` size for the `Abstract` header line, you should definitely write `\section*{Abstract}`.

Comment: To come back to the second part of my inital question, is there a way to display the titel on the same level as the rest of the text and not above it?

Comment: @Jason - Sorry, I hadn't understood earlier what was meant by "same level" -- there's a vertical and a horizontal dimension to consider, right? Anyway, to have the title be in run-in format, use `\paragraph*{Abstract} ...`.